# APNs - Need clarity on background notifications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-push-notifications, usernotifications

I want to understand if my Remote notifications will be throttled based on the payload that I am sending from my backend.

The confusion is due to the introduction of `apns-alert-type` key with possible values of `alert` and `background`.

I want to understand if I set the value of `apns-alert-type` to `alert` but include the `content-available` key in the `aps` dictionary, will such notifications be throttled if sent at a more than the recommended frequency of two or three per hour?

I have documented by understand here in this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13RU0tS9w4OsPpFjqPeoM0DNm045_5CF9DDdhIM9jarQ/edit?usp=sharing

Also adding the same here for quick reference:

| Case No. | apns-push-type | apns-priority | aps.content-available | aps.alert/badge/sound | My understanding | Observation |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | Notification displayed? | App woken up? |
| 1 | background | 5 | 0 | absent | Misconfiguration: content-available should not be 0. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 2 | background | 5 | 0 | present | Misconfiguration: content-available should not be 0. alert/badge/sound is not alllowed. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 3 | background | 5 | 1 | absent | Correct Configuration: This is a background notification. | ❌ | ✅ |
| 4 | background | 5 | 1 | present | Misconfiguration: alert/sound/badge is not allowed. | ❌ | ✅ |
| 5 | background | 10 | 0 | absent | Misconfiguration:priority 10 is not allowed. content-available should not be 0. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 6 | background | 10 | 0 | present | Misconfiguration:priority 10 is not allowed. content-available should not be 0. alert/sound/badge is not allowed. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 7 | background | 10 | 1 | absent | Misconfiguration: priority 10 is not allowed. | ❌ | ✅ |
| 8 | background | 10 | 1 | present | Misconfiguration:priority 10 is not allowed. alert/sound/badge is not allowed. | ❌ | ✅ |
| 9 | alert | 5 | 0 | absent | Misconfiguration: alert/sound/badge should not be absent. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 10 | alert | 5 | 0 | present | Correct configuration: Alert is shown w/o waking up the app. | ✅ | ❌ |
| 11 | alert | 5 | 1 | absent | Misconfiguration: alert/sound/badge should not be absent. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 12 | alert | 5 | 1 | present | Correct configuration: Alert is shown with waking up the app. | ✅ | ✅ |
| 13 | alert | 10 | 0 | absent | Misconfiguration: alert/sound/badge should not be absent. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 14 | alert | 10 | 0 | present | Correct configuration: Alert is shown w/o waking up the app. | ✅ | ❌ |
| 15 | alert | 10 | 1 | absent | Misconfiguration: alert/sound/badge should not be absent. | ❌ | ❌ |
| 16 | alert | 10 | 1 | present | Correct configuration: Alert is shown with waking up the app. | ✅ | ✅ |